# Confusing L-Value and R-Values parentheses

Tags: c++, reference, lvalue, rvalue

In this example [here](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html) at the bottom, there are exemplary l-values defined:

```
  // lvalues:
  int& foo();
  foo() = 42; // ok, foo() is an lvalue
  int* p1 = &foo(); // ok, foo() is an lvalue
```

I am not shure what `foo()` is here? At first sight it looks like a function/method?

Is `int& foo()` the same as `int& foo;` ?

But on the other hand, my compiler says

> Error: 'foo' declared as reference but not initialized int & foo;

Same with the rvalues `foobar()`:

```
  // rvalues:
  int foobar();
  int j = 0;
  j = foobar(); // ok, foobar() is an rvalue
  int* p2 = &foobar(); // error, cannot take the address of an rvalue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is "a function/method", returning a reference to an int. Or, more precisely, this is a declaration of such a function, not definition: it says that such function exists, but does not provide the actual code (because the code is not relevant for the example). Compare how you define functions in header files.

A possible example of code for a similar function:

```
int a, b;
int& foo(bool which) {
    if (which) return a;
    else return b;
} 

...
foo(true) = 10; // works as a = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `foo` is indeed a function. The example is just trying to say "if a function returns an lvalue reference, then the result of calling it is an lvalue."

They probably just mean to say "there is a function `foo` returning an `int&` defined." Although technically, the code is correct as-is: it *is* possible in C++ to declare functions locally:

```
int main()
{
  int foo();
  return foo();
}

int foo()
{
  return 42;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example is referring to the value category of the function call expression `foo()`. In this case, `foo()` is an lvalue because `foo` returns an `int&`.